# How can I overload char*?

Tags: c++, class

I was asked that in a method class receive a char* and copy that in the member of the class, and if I don´t receive any parameter assign "Sin nombre" to the parameter

```
void VEHICULO::Set_Nombre(const char* c){
      //No problem here
}

int main(){
      VEHICULO a;
      a.Set_Nombre("FERRARI");//ITS OK
      a.Set_Nombre();         //the class doesnt know that method
}
```

know how to copy the passed char* or copy "Sin nombre", but when in main I call without a parameter the class doesn´t recognize it, and it should work with the same method, I can´t code the method Set_Nombre(void)

Answer (score 1):

C++ [default arguments](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments).

```
void VEHICULO::Set_Nombre(const char* c = "Sin Nombre")
{
}
```

Comment: If I call Set_Nombre(void) it recognizes the default? I'll try it Thanks!!!!

Comment: You call it *without* parameters and the default is used.